# ES_NUMBER, ES_UPPERCASE and ES_LOWERCASE styles stopped working for Win32 API edit control

Tags: winapi, vb6, editcontrol, createwindowex

We have a very old ("legacy") VB6 code used to create the Windows edit control from scratch. It looks like this:

```
Dim dwStyle As Long
dwStyle = WS_CHILD Or ES_AUTOVSCROLL Or ES_AUTOHSCROLL Or ES_NUMBER Or ES_MULTILINE

m_hwndEdit = CreateWindowExW(0, StrPtr("Edit"), 0, dwStyle, plX, plY, plWidth, plHeight, m_hWnd, 0&, App.hInstance, ByVal 0&)
```

It has worked for years, but now customers report that the ES_NUMBER style has no effect. The same concerns two similar flags, ES_UPPERCASE and ES_LOWERCASE. What can be the problem?

Comment: I have just found a bug in my code - the ES_NUMBER style is overwritten in another place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing has changed. Those styles work just as well today as they have always done. Some possible explanations:

1. Some other program is modifying the window style of your edit control.
2. Some other program is automating your application and setting the text of the control programmatically. For instance, an on-screen keyboard.
3. Your users are pasting values into the edit control rather than typing them.

I suggest that you contact your users and ask them to describe precisely how they are putting these values into the control.

Comment: In fact, this answer did not help anyhow. No other program modifies our control, no external automation. Sure we do know that we can paste "illegal" chars, but it is not the case - I'm talking about normal typing. And we can reproduce that problem on different pc's.

Comment: Well nothing has changed in windows. Those window styles work just as they always have done. If you can reproduce it, you can create an sscce.

Comment: I thought it could be a subtle change in the recent versions of OS I didn't note (perhaps, related to a combination of other styles). I'm going to experiment and see why these flags may not work. Will write about my researches as soon as I have any result.

Comment: I think calling my answer useless is a bit strong. These flags behave the same now as always. You should make an SSCCE.

Comment: It was the first edition - later I changed it to "did not help". Your answer "nothing changed" is good, but it does not give me any practical idea what things I should check in MY code. Sorry for any mutual misunderstanding.

Comment: The answer should help. It tells you to look in your code. What have you changed recently? Anyway, you need to make that sscce.

Comment: I do not remember what I changed "recently" in the last 10 years ;). Yes, I agreed that your answer "nothing changed" is good for me as I know that the ES_NUMBER flag still should work as earlier. Gimme some time (a day or so) to experiment. It is a part of a big project, so it is not easy to make a SSCCE. I'll get you back as soon as I have anything to say. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50029/discussion-between-tecman-and-david-heffernan)